# How to invoke an executable on USB stick with unknown drive letter assigned?

Tags: batch-file

I am using a Sandisk USB stick and it has a built-in software called secure access software with vault access.

I want to invoke this secure access software application from command line.

Below is my batch file. It does recognize the drive and I am able to see the file on the drive. But every time I get this error:

> the filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

The batch code:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "myDrive="

for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
    if not defined myDrive vol %%a: >nul 2>nul && (
        if exist "%%a:\RunSanDiskSecureAccess_Win.exe" set "myDrive=%%a:"
    )
)
```

This detects the drive, but code below fails to invoke the application.

```
if defined myDrive (
    echo drive found [%myDrive%]
) else (
    echo USB drive has not been found
    rem cd [%myDrive%]:\RunSanDiskSecureAccess_Win.exe

    "[%myDrive%]:\RunSanDiskSecureAccess_Win.exe"
)

endlocal
```

Comment: How is a "button" in a "webpage" to initialize such a script?

Comment: Assuming the "webpage" is somehow able to execute the batch file, unless `RunSanDiskSecureAccess_Win.exe` is a folder, the ending backslash should not be there.

Comment: sorry leave that webpage concept i am only after invoking an application from cmd i have edited my question..

Comment: Thanks MC ND  it has detected the drive but to how to invoke that application if  i am right can i use this... `echo USB drive has not been found
        rem cd [%myDrive%]:\RunSanDiskSecureAccess_Win.exe

        "[%myDrive%]:\RunSanDiskSecureAccess_Win.exe"    

)
      
    endlocal`

Comment: The `[]` characters where included only as visual delimiters. Remove them. Also, if you read the `set myDrive` line, you will see that the colon is included in the value, so, to call the executable you should use `%myDrive%\RunSanDiskSecureAccess_Win.exe`

Answer (score 0):

A possible batch code for this task is:

```
@echo off
for %%# in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
    vol %%#: >nul 2>nul
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        if exist "%%#:\RunSanDiskSecureAccess_Win.exe" (
            start "Secure Access" "%%#:\RunSanDiskSecureAccess_Win.exe"
            exit /B
        )
    )
)
echo USB drive has not been found.
echo.
pause
```

For each drive letter command **vol** is executed which exits with value 0 on volume exists or with a value greater 0 on volume not existing. The standard output on volume existing or the error message on volume not existing are redirected to device **nul**, see [using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

If exit code of **vol** is *not greater or equal* 1 which means if exit code is equal 0 as no negative value returned ever by **vol**, an existence check is done for the executable to start.

If the executable of the application exists on current drive, the application is started in a new process and the processing of this batch file is exited immediately because there is no need to check existence of any other drive. The first double quoted string is interpreted as title of new process by command **start** which is the reason for `Secure Access`.

But if the executable could not be found on any drive, an error message is printed into console window and batch processing is halted to give the user the possibility to read the message until user presses any key or closes the console window.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `start /?`
- `vol /?`